# Ошибка при передачи управления другому сервлету

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Я пытаюсь передать управление от одного сервлета к другому при помощи: `req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").forward(req, resp);` и получаю нужную `jsp` страницу, но при попытке использовать формы на `index.jsp` повторно, получается что запросы продолжают идти к предыдущему сервлету.

Почему так происходит и как мне это исправить?

Это стартовая страница при первом обращении к ней ведет себя правильно:

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" action=""> // index.jsp примаплен к корню поэтому пустая строка(может тут проблема..?)

        <input type="radio" name="act" value="addition" id="add"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Ok" name="Ok"><br>

    </form>
</body>

// web.xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlets.HomePageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

И страница которая добавляет пользователя в базу:

```
<body>
    <form method="post" action="addition">

        <input type="text" required placeholder="name" name="name"><br>
        <input type="text" required placeholder="login" name="login"><br>
        <input type="text" required placeholder="email" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="add">

    </form>
</body>

// web.xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlets.AddUserServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddUserServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addition</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

И в конце работы `doPost` я хочу перенаправить снова на `index.jsp` :

```
req.getRequestDispatcher(format("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp", select)).forward(req, resp);
```

Но на этот раз, обращения с `index.jsp` идут только к `AddUserServlet` а мне надо чтобы при возвращении на сраницу `index.jsp` запросы шли опять к `HomePageServlet` как при первом запросе.

Помогите пожалуйста исправить. Спасибо.

Comment: Да. Так и должно быть. Делая forward Вы на самом деле оставляете браузер на том же url. Получается страница, которая динамически изменяет своё содержимое. И ссылки (и href и action) вычисляются исходя и текущего url (который не поменялся) и Вы попадаете всегда обратно. Вам нужно заставить браузер перейти на другой url. Часто применяют POST-REDIRECT-GET. В AddUserServlet место `forward на /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp` примените `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath())`. Это выдаст браузеру инструкцию перейти на указанный url

Comment: @Sergey да но такая запись редиректит всегда в корень сайта. А как быть если я хочу перенаправить пользователя еще на какую-то страницу у которой есть только метод `doPost()`?

Comment: response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/page")

Comment: @Sergey я так пробовал но все равно на ту же страницу перебрасыват только вот с таки адресом, это наверно сработает для jsp которые не в web-inf лежат?

Comment: Убедитесь, что `/page` соответствует <url-pattern> сервлета, на который хотите попасть.

Comment: @Sergey да я понял он хочет сделать редирект на get метод а мне нужно чтобы редирект шел на post.